# why do we get resource exists error in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Probably something which i don’t understand for quiet some time.

Executed plan and then apply. Created few resources and failed since the snapshot was not found.

```
aws_lambda_function.LambdaShipRdsLog: Creation complete
aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group.default: Creation complete
aws_db_parameter_group.default: Creation complete
aws_s3_bucket.RdsLogShipment: Creation complete
Error applying plan:
```

1 error(s) occurred:

```
* aws_rds_cluster.default: Error creating RDS Cluster: DBClusterSnapshotNotFoundFault: DBClusterSnapshot not found: xy
    status code: 404, request id: 123
```

So, i fixed the issue and trigger the plan and apply once again , but end up getting the resource exists error.

3 error(s) occurred:

```
* aws_db_parameter_group.default: Error creating DB Parameter Group: DBParameterGroupAlreadyExists: Parameter group xyz already exists
    status code: 400, request id: 123
* aws_lambda_function.LambdaShipRdsLog: Error creating Lambda function: ResourceConflictException: Function already exist: xyz
    status code: 409, request id: 123
* aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group.default: Error creating DB Cluster Parameter Group: DBParameterGroupAlreadyExists: Parameter group xyz already exists
    status code: 400, request id: 123
```

As per my understanding, any resource that are being created will be updated in the state file and the next time when i execute `terraform plan` for the config, it knows that the resource already exists and it will skip it, but that doesn’t looks like the case. Can someone explain what I am missing? Thanks.

Comment: Can you paste your terraform code and full log? Worst case: run `terraform destroy` and then `terraform plan`.

Comment: well, its very huge config file. Let me know, if you don't understand my question. Thanks.

Comment: destroy worked fine, and i am going to trigger again. Just want to clear on my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely what's happening without seeing the Terraform files and the plan/apply directly is that you have either a manually created resource with the same name or terraform created a resource and it was deleted by hand.  When you delete things by hand sometimes it creates dependency problems.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you.  BUT HOW DO WE FIX IT???  How do we tell terraform that if something we request it to build already exists, just keep going?

Comment: @MartinThurn hopefully you worked this out by now, but for anyone else looking at this question: you need to import existing resources into the Terraform state, as described here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/index.html

Comment: I had this happen to me without any manual intervention. Just tried to apply the plan multiple times.